# mysql query to populate current query row with value from previous row

Tags: mysql

I have a table, it has datetime fields for `intime` and `outtime`.

what I want to do is loop through the table with a query and change the intime to the previous records outtime.

this way there will be a constant flow through my data with no 'time losses'

The image below shows my table currently and what I want to achieve.

[image]
You can find a fiddle for this example here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40b10/10

Now I understand that the table design etc is not optimal, just looking for the logic on how to get this working.

to summarize.

how do I make the `inTime` equal to the latest `outtime` before the current intime?

soe logic of what I am trying to do is below but does not work correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ifnull` is needed just to display the first `intime` correctly.

```
SELECT mov.vehicle,
       ifnull((SELECT max(temp.outtime)
               FROM movement temp
               WHERE temp.outtime< mov.intime),mov.intime) as intime_calc,
       mov.outtime
FROM movement mov
ORDER BY mov.intime
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40b10/23

If you have some records where the `intime` is already equal to the previous record `outtime` you might want to change the query to:

```
SELECT mov.vehicle,
       ifnull((SELECT max(temp.outtime)
               FROM movement temp
               WHERE temp.outtime<= mov.intime
               AND mov.ID <> temp.ID),mov.intime) as intime_calc,
       mov.outtime
FROM movement mov
ORDER BY mov.intime
```